# In sqlite, what is the meaning of value of the Table B-Tree Interior Cells when we have multi level interior table b tree pages?

Tags: database, sqlite

I am writing a python parser for database created by sqlite and studying sqlite's file format. I have carefully read the official document https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html and some supplement material like https://forensicsfromthesausagefactory.blogspot.com/2011/05/analysis-of-record-structure-within.html .

It is mentioned that we have mainly 4 types of pages, and I dont understand how Interior Table B-Tree pages works.

I made some print message to help me understanding the problem. Here is the first case. I have a db with 100 records and I dont set any primary key or index:

```
page type 5, page number 2
[9, 98]
[8, 84]
[7, 70]
[6, 56]
[5, 42]
[4, 28]
[3, 14]
page type 13, page number 3
    skip actual data in leaf table b tree pages
page type 13, page number 4
page type 13, page number 5
page type 13, page number 6
page type 13, page number 7
page type 13, page number 8
page type 13, page number 9
page type 13, page number 10
```

This example works fine to me. page number 2 is an interior table b tree page, the first element points to leaf table b tree page which contains the actual data and the second element points to the last rowid of each leaf table b tree page.

Then I increase the record number in database from 100 to 1000. Here is the output:

```
page type 5, page number 2
[5, 104]
[6, 90]
[7, 76]
[8, 62]
[9, 48]
[10, 34]
[11, 20]
[12, 133]
[13, 119]
[14, 105]
[15, 91]
[16, 77]
[17, 64]
[18, 50]
[19, 36]
[20, 22]
[21, 8]
[22, 121]
[23, 107]
[24, 93]
[25, 79]
[26, 65]
[27, 51]
[28, 37]
[29, 23]
[30, 9]
[31, 122]
[32, 108]
[33, 94]
[34, 80]
[35, 66]
[36, 52]
[37, 38]
[38, 24]
[39, 10]
[40, 123]
[41, 109]
[42, 95]
[43, 81]
[44, 67]
[45, 53]
[46, 39]
[47, 25]
[48, 11]
[49, 124]
[50, 110]
[51, 96]
[52, 82]
[53, 68]
[54, 54]
[55, 40]
[56, 26]
[57, 12]
[58, 125]
[59, 111]
[60, 97]
[61, 83]
[62, 69]
[63, 55]
[64, 41]
[65, 27]
[66, 13]
[67, 126]
[68, 112]
[69, 98]
[70, 84]
[71, 70]
[72, 56]
[73, 42]
[74, 28]
[4, 14]
page type 13, page number 3
page type 13, page number 4
page type 13, page number 5
page type 13, page number 6
page type 13, page number 7
page type 13, page number 8
page type 13, page number 9
page type 13, page number 10
page type 13, page number 11
page type 13, page number 12
page type 13, page number 13
page type 13, page number 14
page type 13, page number 15
page type 13, page number 16
page type 13, page number 17
page type 13, page number 18
... Skip more leaf pages
```

As you can see, this time the row id of page number 2 (interior table b tree page) does not always descend. It seems to loop in a range:

```
[57, 12]
[58, 125]
[59, 111]
[60, 97]
[61, 83]
[62, 69]
[63, 55]
[64, 41]
[65, 27]
[66, 13] <- Here, instead of finding the records from 126 to 140, it points to 13. However, after checking the content of page, the content does match the record from 126 to 140. So why is the row id point to 13 here?
[67, 126] <- I could find records from 112 to 126 in page number 67, no problem
[68, 112]
[69, 98]
[70, 84]
[71, 70]
[72, 56]
[73, 42]
[74, 28]
[4, 14] <- I could find the first 14 records in page number 4, no problem
```

I am wondering why is the rowid from line [66, 13] point to this wierd number. According to the document:

> Table B-Tree Interior Cell (header 0x05):
>
> A 4-byte big-endian page number which is the left child pointer. A
>   varint which is the integer key

The second element should just be the integer key, which is rowid in my example.

In my next example, I further increase the data record from 1000 to 500k. The main difference is that there would be multiple level of interior table b table pages. I also found some wired thing to my parent level interior table b tree pages:

```
page type 5, page number 2
[35417, 3938]
... skip some records
[9083, 1076]
[8684, 1094]
[8285, 984]
[7886, 1000]
[7487, 895]
[7088, 913]
[6689, 802]
[6290, 821]
[5891, 712]
[5492, 731]
[5093, 622]
[4694, 642]
[4295, 534]
[3896, 552]
[3497, 442]
[3098, 458]
[2699, 349]
[2300, 366]
[1901, 256]
[1501, 273]
[1029, 162]
[517, 125]
[516, 76]
page type 13, page number 3
page type 13, page number 4
page type 13, page number 5
page type 13, page number 6
... skip more pages
... skip more pages
... skip more pages
```

For the print msg in page number 2, I understand the left element is the child page number of interior table b tree pages since we have a lot of data and there would be multi-level interior table b tree pages. But again what does the value rowid part means? I have 500k records so the row id should range from 1 to 500,000. Why in this example it only ranges to 4k?